# Null reference exception when watching value in debugger works

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am overriding the equals function on a class of mine and am getting a null point exception despite the fact that when I enter the same code in the "watch" section of the debugger there is no exception.

Here is my code (anything compared with an `==` is a string or primitive type):

```
return this.workOrder == i.workOrder
    && this.upi == i.upi
    && this.testName == i.testName
    && BasicFunctions.ArraysEqual(this.testTrays, i.testTrays)
    && this.supplyVoltage == i.supplyVoltage
    && this.supplyAmperage == i.supplyAmperage
    && this.commandResults == null ? i.commandResults == null : this.commandResults.Equals(i.commandResults)
    && this.id == i.id;
```

The view from the watch window:
[image: Screenshot of my watch window with one line for each section of the return statement. All but the supplyAmperage section are true.]

The comparison of `commandResults` is the only thing that could result in a null exception and as you can see from the code this scenario should be handled by the ternary operator. Not only that but in the instances where it fails it should never have reached that section as the line should have stopped executing on the first false section. How can this be happening?

**Edit:**
As requested here are the details of the exception (note that this has be called by the ArrayEquals function and the exception is not inside the one used in the code listed)

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
  Source="ATE"
  StackTrace:
       at ATE.Network.TestLocationListener.TestClientInformation.Equals(Object obj) in C:\Users\jdudley\git\ATE\ATE\ATE\Network\TestLocationListener.cs:line 85
       at ATE.BasicFunctions.ArraysEqual[T](T[] a1, T[] a2) in C:\Users\jdudley\git\ATE\ATE\ATE\BasicFunctions.cs:line 150
       at ATE_Remote_Controller.Form1.remoteClient1_StatusUpdated(Object sender) in C:\Users\jdudley\git\ATE\ATE\ATE Remote Controller\Form1.cs:line 25
       at ATE.Network.RemoteClient.statusRead(JSONReadCallbackResult res) in C:\Users\jdudley\git\ATE\ATE\ATE\Network\RemoteClient.cs:line 153
       at ATE.Network.JSONReader.Receive(IAsyncResult ar) in C:\Users\jdudley\git\ATE\ATE\ATE\Network\JSONReader.cs:line 236
       at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
       at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
       at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you create a simplified example that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Also, somewhat offtopic, your code can probably be improved by replacing the ternary statement with `object.Equals(this.commandResults, i.commandResults)`.

Comment: What exactly does the exception say?

Comment: maybe `i.commandResults` is null.

Comment: @MikeH That's not right, you can't call a static method like that and he checks if it's null first.

Comment: @TimS. You're right...comments "cleaned" :)

Comment: @TimS. I cannot replicate the exception in other code, otherwise I would gladly provide a simplified example.

Comment: How about breaking that line into multiple lines to figure out which statement is causing the problem?

Comment: @MikeH That was what I thought I was doing by examining each of them separately with a watch.

Comment: Not sure without looking it up, but how does the ternary operator compare in precedence to `&&`?  Could the final line be being used as part of the 3rd part of the ternary?  It would then be different to your watches

Comment: Note that not all of your watches are executing in that screen shot.  All of the greyed out ones were previously evalutated.

Comment: I think @JamesThorpe is right.  try putting your ternary operator inside parenthesis.  Specifically I'm guessing that everything before the `?` is used by the ternary operator.

Comment: @JamesThorpe You've got it right. Make that an answer and you've got my vote.

Comment: @MikeH I think you are correct, since the error does not happen when all the other values are equal. Ops I mena juharr, got my eyes crossed

Comment: Beaten to it, and more correctly too, by @juharr - I hadn't considered the boolean part before the `?` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that what you have is equivalent to this

```
return this.workOrder == (i.workOrder
    && this.upi == i.upi
    && this.testName == i.testName
    && BasicFunctions.ArraysEqual(this.testTrays, i.testTrays)
    && this.supplyVoltage == i.supplyVoltage
    && this.supplyAmperage == i.supplyAmperage
    && this.commandResults == null) ? 
        i.commandResults == null : 
        (this.commandResults.Equals(i.commandResults)
        && this.id == i.id);
```

When what you want is this.

```
return this.workOrder == i.workOrder
    && this.upi == i.upi
    && this.testName == i.testName
    && BasicFunctions.ArraysEqual(this.testTrays, i.testTrays)
    && this.supplyVoltage == i.supplyVoltage
    && this.supplyAmperage == i.supplyAmperage
    && (this.commandResults == null ? 
        i.commandResults == null : 
        this.commandResults.Equals(i.commandResults))
    && this.id == i.id;
```

Basically if any of the previous statements are false, like `this.supplyAmperage == i.supplyAmperage` will cause the ternary operator to execute the `this.commandResults.Equals(i.commandResults)` even if `this.commandResults` is `null`.

Comment: You can also add parentheses in the first example from after the `:` to the end.

Comment: And the reference for this behavior is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx